# Update table to display total by grouped columns SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sum, concatenation, insert-update

I am working with a table that stores amounts at monthly level. This table gets insert/updated by many stored procedures.

What I am trying to accomplish: I'd like update the table so it has unique rows based on following column combination:

```
Property_ID, Accound, AccountDescription, jobcd, costcd, asofdate
```

Also, update will ***SUM*** the amount by above combination. However, the `Update_ID` column will also get updated and combine `step_id`.

In summary, I want one row that will display amount total by columns listed above.  It will delete rows that were used to create this total amount. However, it will retain `step_Id` information and add it to `Update_ID` column.

Is there a way to do this without involving many steps? It is a big table with no indexes.

```
declare @temp as table
                 (
                    ID int,
                    step_ID varchar(120),
                    Update_ID varchar(1000),
                    Property_ID int,
                    Account int,
                    AccountDescription varchar(120),
                    jobcd varchar(20),
                    costcd varchar(20),
                    asofdate date, 
                    amount money
                )

INSERT INTO @temp (ID, step_ID, Update_ID, Property_ID, Account, AccountDescription, jobcd, costcd, asofdate, amount)
VALUES (1, 'Step 1.1', NULL, 50950, 41510, 'CAM&taxes billed', 'TMORFRA01' , 'LMORFRA01', '2019-09-01', '20.00'),
       (2, 'Step 1.2', 'Step 1.0', 50950, 41510, 'CAM&taxes billed', 'TMORFRA01' , 'LMORFRA01', '2019-09-01', '180.00'),
       (3, 'Step 1.1', NULL, 50950, 40110, 'Base rent billed', 'TMORFRA01' , 'LMORFRA01', '2019-09-01', '80.00'),
       (4, 'Step 1.2', NULL, 50950, 40110, 'Base rent billed', 'TMORFRA01' , 'LMORFRA01', '2019-09-01', '100.00'),
       (5, 'Step 1.3', NULL, 50950, 40110, 'Base rent billed', 'TMORFRA01' , 'LMORFRA01', '2019-09-01', '200.00')

SELECT * FROM @temp
```

Expected result:

```
    declare @ExpectedResult as table
    (
    ID int ,
    step_ID varchar(120),
    Update_ID varchar(1000),
    Property_ID int,
    Account int,
    AccountDescription varchar(120),
    jobcd varchar(20),
    costcd varchar(20),
    asofdate date, 
    amount money
    )

INSERT INTO @ExpectedResult (ID, step_ID, Update_ID, Property_ID, Account, AccountDescription, jobcd, costcd, asofdate, amount)
VALUES (1, 'Step 1.1', 'Step 1.0; Step 1.1 + Step 1.2: Sum Amounts;', 50950, 41510, 'CAM&taxes billed', 'TMORFRA01' , 'LMORFRA01', '2019-09-01', '200.00'),
       (3, 'Step 1.1', 'Step 1.1 + Step 1.2 + Step 1.3: Sum Amounts', 50950, 40110, 'Base rent billed', 'TMORFRA01' , 'LMORFRA01', '2019-09-01', '380.00')

SELECT * FROM @ExpectedResult
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to continually update the data. It'd be a lot of processing, and then you lose the integrity of the data. Instead, i'd create a `PROCEDURE` or `VIEW` with this type of result set. Then, when you want to return it, you can query it and never lose the normalized data which you may need later on down the road. With that said, here's the code to do that (except you won't use the `order by`):

```
--create view... or create proc which ever...
select 
    ID = min(ID)
    ,step_id = min(step_id)
    ,Updated_ID = STUFF(
                    STUFF((
                          SELECT ' + '  + t2.step_id
                          FROM @temp t2
                          WHERE 
                            t2.Property_ID = t.Property_ID
                            and t2.Account = t.Account
                            and t2.jobcd = t.jobcd
                            and t2.costcd = t.costcd
                          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') + ': Sum Amounts', 1, 1, '')
    ,Property_ID
    ,Account
    ,AccountDescription
    ,jobcd
    ,costcd
    ,asofdate
    ,amount = sum(amount)
from @temp t
group by
    Property_ID
    ,Account
    ,AccountDescription
    ,jobcd
    ,costcd
    ,asofdate
order by
    ID
```